# Django: Two FormViews in a Template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

everyone!
I want to display to forms in a template

My forms are:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(
        required=True)
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(
        required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(
        required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea)

class CVCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CV
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I have two FormViews:

```
class ContactView(FormView):

    form_class = ContactForm
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('webpage:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
        contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = 'Name: {}\nPhone:{}\n{}'.format(form.cleaned_data['contact_name'], form.cleaned_data['contact_phone'], form.cleaned_data['message'],)
        send_mail(subject,
                  message,
                  contact_email,
                  ['maumg1196@gmail.com'])
        return context


class CVCreateView(FormView):

    form_class = CVCreateForm
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('webpage:home')

    def form_valid(self):
        context = super(CVCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        form_owner = form.cleaned_data['owner']
        form_cv = form.cleaned_data['cv']
        form_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        send_mail('Curriculum Vitae',
                  form_cv,
                  form_email,
                  ['maumg1196@gmail.com'])
        cv = CV(owner=form_owner, email=form_email, cv=form_cv)
        cv.save()
        return context
```

(Note: In the second form the 'form_cv' is gonna be a PDF file I think that isn't a problem to send the email but I don't know very well.)
I want to display this two FormViews in a TemplateView

Thanks :)

Comment: Just to let you know, you've left what looks like your email in your code in the views. Call me paranoid, but as this is a public post I usually prefer to change this to something more like ```myemail@gmail.com``` :)

Answer (score 1):

In your TemplateView you need to just need to pass the two forms in the context as follows:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .forms import ContactView, CVCreateView


class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/my_template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contact_form'] = ContactView()
        context['cv_form'] = CVCreateView()
        return context
```

In the template you set the form `action` attribute to point to the URL of the appropriate view, `ContactView` or `CVCreateView`, so something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'contact_form' %}" method="POST">
     {{ contact_form }}
</form>

<form action="{% url 'cv_form' %}" method="POST">
     {{ cv_form }}
</form>
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: I did it like you, but now the template show me something like this in the two forms:

    <webpage.views.ContactView object at 0xb4ed9f6c>

Comment: Change your urls.py to be like ```url(r'^$', MyTemplateView.as_view(), name='my_template_view'),```

Comment: This is my url: url(regex=r'^two_forms$', view=views.TwoFormsView.as_view(), name='forms'),